# Ruby PostgreSQL tutorials

Tags: ruby, postgresql

I am trying to write a ruby script that interacts with a PostgreSQL database. I am trying to piece together how to do this from the documentation, but a nice tutorial or sample code would work wonders to decrease the amount of time to get this working. If anyone has a link, some tips or has some code they could share I would be most grateful.

Edit, made this note more clear:

Note: this isn't to do with rails ActiveRecord, I am writing a Ruby script that will be involved in a program that is completely independent from Rails.

Comment: hmm, I think everyone is kinda confused. Im trying to use ActiveRecord on my own, not in rails. However I will be pleased to see any information about database connectivity in ruby, as I frequently find that there is a better way to implement things. It will also be a good resource for future readers.

Comment: You can use ActiveRecord separately from Rails, or use another ORM just as Sequel or DataMapper. I prefer Sequel; I'd recommend using an ORM instead of hand-coding the SQL for a particular DBM. If, in the future, you need to change to a different database manager, it's trivial with an ORM if it supports it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need to require the `pg` gem and establish the connection to the DB:

```
require 'pg'
# require 'active_record'  # uncomment for not Rails environment

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:adapter => "postgresql",
                                        :username => "username",
                                        :password => "password",
                                        :database => "database")
```

When you define models to inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base` they will use this database connection. Everything else should work like it does in Rails.

Comment: Why is this answer marked accepted?  It doesn't answer your question, you noted it does not deal with Rails or ActiveRecord.

Comment: He's writing a simple ruby script, he doesn't want to import an entire non-related framework :/

Comment: Active Record is perfectly fine for working with a database connection. You can also use the Sequel gem if you want something a bit lighter. AR was what I knew at the time and therefore that is what I recommended.

Comment: When I try this solution I get this error:

Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile

Answer (score 21):

Please be more specific about what postgresql  library you're using.

I'm going to assume the 'pg' gem, apart from ActiveRecord.

The project source has an html file that might be helpful.
Go to https://bitbucket.org/ged/ruby-pg/src/b477174160c8/doc/postgres.html
Then click "raw" at the upper right side of the html. Open the file in your web browser.

This sample code helps you connect (copied from the html file):

```
require "postgres"
conn = PGconn.connect("localhost", 5432, "", "", "test1")
# or: conn = PGconn.open('dbname=test1')
res = conn.exec("select * from a;")
```

The res object is a PGResult. Scroll down to that section in the html to see what methods you can call.

This link has a PGResult example:
http://rubydoc.info/gems/pg/0.10.0/PGresult

Excerpt:

```
require 'pg'
conn = PGconn.open(:dbname => 'test')
res  = conn.exec('SELECT 1 AS a, 2 AS b, NULL AS c')
res.getvalue(0,0) # '1'
res[0]['b']       # '2'
res[0]['c']       # nil
```

Comment: Btw, that html file might be outdated. I think you need to require 'pg' instead of 'postgres'.

Comment: Why do ruby and postgresql often tend to work together? Is there any reason for this?

Comment: @stt106 If you're asking why postgresql is often used with ruby apps, that's only because the app developer chooses to do so. I'm also not confident in saying that ruby devs use postgresql more often mysql (for example). If that's not what you mean, please rephrase the question.

Comment: That’s what I meant but I can’t rephrase it as it’s not allowed to edit the comments anymore. I do see a lot of companies using both ruby and PostgreSQL though.

Answer (score 17):

I confirm, "postgres" package is outdated, you need "pg".

It tooks me lot of time just to get a basic `select * from films` working with ruby and postgres. As I am kind, here is my code:

postgres preparation (database=megatest user=roger pass=123456 table=films)

```
$ su postgres 
psql 
CREATE USER roger WITH PASSWORD '123456';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE megatest to roger;

megatest=# GRANT SELECT ON films TO PUBLIC;
```

PG package preparation

```
sudo gem install pg
```

Ruby Code

```
require 'pg'

conn=PGconn.connect( :hostaddr=>"127.0.0.1", :port=>5432, :dbname=>"megatest", :user=>"roger", :password=>'123456')
# or for a non IP address :host => 'my.host.name.com' instead of hostaddr

# run the query
res = conn.exec("SELECT * FROM films")

# Ran only once in order to get field Name
fieldArray=res.fields()
fieldArray.each do |elem|
    print "elem="+elem+"\n"
end

# print data from the query
res.each{ |row|
    puts "Code="+row["code"]  +" title="+row["title"] +" did="+row["did"] +" date_prod="+row["date_prod"] +" kind="+row["kind"] +" len="+row["len"]
}
```

Results

```
root@eblain-VirtualBox:/home/eblain/ruby# ruby postgresTest.rb
Code=UA502 title=Bananas did=105 date_prod=1971-07-13 kind=Comedy len=01:22:00
Code=UA503 title=Cowboy did=105 date_prod=1979-07-13 kind=Horror len=01:32:00
Code=UA544 title=YoBro did=105 date_prod=1981-07-13 kind=Action len=01:42:00
```

Comment: It is difficult to decipher your answer. Can you fix the formatting so it's more usable?

Comment: What would the hostname be for a local postgres instillation on a mac?

Answer (score 4):

For parametrized SQL statements, you should use `PGconn#exec_params`, e.g.

```
conn = PGconn.new(:dbname => 'test')
conn.exec_params(
    'INSERT INTO comedians (first_name, last_name) VALUES ($1, $2)',
    ['Louis', 'CK'])
conn.close
```

Source: http://deveiate.org/code/pg/PGconn.html

[Look here](http://rubydoc.info/gems/pg/0.11.0/PGconn#constructor_details) for a complete list of parameters that can be passed to the `PGconn` constructor.